# How to install two oracle versions, 11g and 12c?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I want to install Oracle 11g and 12c in my computer for 2 diferent applications.
I have already Oracle 11g installed and it works very well, but when I installed 12c it didn't work and 11g stop running not knowing why. I had to uninstall it, and now 11g is working again, altought I still needing to install 12c but I don't know how to do it wothout crashing 11g.

I want to know if someone of you can tell me how to do it and how can I change between both instances.

Thanks.

Comment: What OS is this?  Is it the client only or the database?

Comment: Windows 7. I need just the database, because with sql developer i can connect to both isn't it?

Comment: Your last response still isn't clear to the question @Lunc asked.  Do you need to install a 12c _database_, or just a client? It sounds like all you need is the client software.  SQL Dev is a client application.  It does not contain nor come with an actual database.  It is certainly quite common to install multiple versions of either database or client.  Unfortunately, in your opening post, "it didn't work" is completly devoid of actionable information.  Please explain "didn't work" and "stopped running".

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install both Oracle 11GR2 and 12C, then install in different Oracle Homes.

Please note that when you install Oracle 12C, the service account for that database, will override any other Oracle permissions. So if you're using directories where your table-spaces are living in the same place for each database version, then the permissions for 11G will be overridden by 12c permissions. You'll need to manually adjust the permissions on the file locations respectively.

If you have troubles with listeners, then you'll need to indicate different listeners and their associated Oracle Home.

Please take a look here if you find any troubles with the listeners after having both databases installed.: [Oracle 11g and 12c on same windows machine, 12c listener fails to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24157916/oracle-11g-and-12c-on-same-windows-machine-12c-listener-fails-to-start)

If you have any problems then you can always review the trace files on the database, to determine why one isn't starting.

$ORACLE_HOME\virtual\diag\rdbms{SID}{SID}\alert\log.xml
OR
$ORACLE_HOME\virtual\diag\rdbms{SID}{SID}\trace\